# About draggable elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I don't have much experience with jQuery.

I have 4 `li` elements and a draggable block. When I drag from green to blue, first I need my dragging block to stand behind blue and not go out from the borders of the container, meaning that my draggable element must be always snap into the container.

When my draggable element stand behind blue, the background color must be changed from brown to red.

Can anybody help me? Because I don't really know how to do this. All what I have at this moment is: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/galvanchi/BrZaa/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="container"  class="ui-widget-header">
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="menuElement1"></li>
    <li id="menuElement2"></li>
    <li id="menuElement3"></li>
    <li id="menuElement4"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
body {
    background-color: brown;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#menu,
#draggable {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#draggable {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
}
#menu {
    margin-left: -40px;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 50px;
}
#menuElement1 {
    background-color: green;
}
#menuElement2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
#menuElement3 {
    background-color: black;
}
#menuElement4 {
    background-color: red;
}
#container {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ snap: ".ui-widget-header" });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrZaa/2/)

You'd do well to read this article on [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) from the jQuery docs. Basically you were half way there, you need to make an element (the blue box, with id #menuElement2) droppable to provide a target for a draggable element

```
$('#menuElement2').droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    //Do something here...
  }
});
```

Within the drop function (this fired when the block is dropped on the target) you need to perform your action.

```
$('body').css({'background-color': 'red'});
```

This adds a custom css rule to the body that changes the colour, again check out the jQuery docs - search for 'jQuery css'.

Hope this helps :)

Update: I just updated the fiddle again to make it revert back to brown when you change selection - not sure if you wanted this but it can be easily removed by commenting out the css change within the drag function.